# Query based on related refs in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Given this database structure in Firebase Realtime database,

[image]

I would like to get list of quotes based on a specific category.

If user selects "Motivation" then all quotes under that category should be returned. For e.g. in the above structure, `quotes ID: 1,2,5` are under category "Motivation" so if a user selects motivation (from a dropdown in UI) then only the quotes ID: 1,2,5 should be returned in the snapshot.

How to form a firebase query such that only 1,2,5 are returned in the snapshot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no single query that can do this in Firebase, since the Realtime Database doesn't support any form of server-side joins.

So you will need to:

1. Attach a listener to the category under `/category`.
2. Loop over the child nodes in the snapshot you get.
3. Attach an individual listener for each key under `/quotes`

This approach is not nearly as slow as many developers initially think, since Firebase pipelines the requests where possible. See [Speed up fetching posts for my social network app by using query instead of observing a single event repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)

Comment: Can u pls give a quick example, particularly expressing this statement `Attach an individual listener for each key under /quotes`. thanks